# Is there a benefit to having several connection pools over one single connection pool?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, iis

We are taking a (large) legacy application that uses a single connection string everywhere so they can use a single connection pool.

The plan is to take a service orientation and break up the application into smaller sub applications.  Each one of these applications will be hosted in IIS and I am trying to figure out if there is a benefit of the app pool for each application having a different identity tied to that application, i.e. [Domain]\SVC_ApplicationA rather than having all the app pools use the same identity and therefore a single connection pool.

While we have a single (SQL Server) database now, as we move to this new model the plan is to start with a new schema inside the original DB for each application.  The dbo schema will be deprecated as legacy and in order to access dbo, the applications must do so through objects (views, procs, etc...) in their respective schema.  The caveat being that an application schema is only allowed to access objects within its own schema or from dbo, not from other application schemas.

If each application had its own identity, we could secure each schema independently.  My concern is that if we have 50 applications we would have 50 connection pools.  Would this negatively impact performance?  I know this is a loaded question but I am really only asking in the abstract.

Thanks!

Comment: "...all the app pools use the same identity and therefore a single connection pool" - AFAIK Connection pools are not shared between AppDomains, so you will be as many connection pools as applications independent of the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doc. If you're using impersonation in your web site and AD security in the database, you already have one pool per user who has used the site. You can set a max pool size as part of the connection string, but I've never had a problem with this, even with 100+ users.

Also, Connections are pooled at the process level. If you have multiple Web Apps each with their own AppPool (and thus process) then each process will have its own Connection Pool. I don't believe that a connection takes very much memory (certainly not MBs!) and I've never seen a problem due to Connection Pools - save when in one case with a very slow DB and Oracle Connection pool hit the max number of connections and threw errors while refusing to open new ones: a symptom of the slowness of the DB, rather than anything wrong with pooling.

Splitting up the legacy DB into multiple schemas sounds sensible. You'll have a bit more management overhead, setting permissions on the relevant bits, but not too much I should think.